# Finding number of pages of a website

Tags: html, web

I want to find the **number of pages** of a website. Usually what I look for is a `sitemap` but I just encountered a site which does not have a sitemap so I am out of ideas of how to find its total pages. I tried to `Google` the `URL` but that did not helped much. Is there any other way we can find out the pages of a website?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way would be to grab yourself some link checking software (I use Integrity on a Mac), set it to crawl the types of pages your interested in counting and let it run. Once it's crawled the site you'll have the total number of pages

Comment: the most accurate way would be if you had access to the source of the site, unfortunately even if you use a link crawler you will miss all the unlinked pages

Comment: A worst condition can be if the site is banned by the search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a better solution myself. You can go to **Google Advanced Search** and restrict the search results to `your domain name`. Leave everything else empty. It would give you the list of all pages cached by Google.

Answer (score 2):

Ask Google "site:yourdomain.com"
This gives you all indexed pages.

Or use the free tool "Xenu". It crawls the whole site. But it won't find sites which have no internal links pointing to them. You can also export a sitemap with it.

Comment: Oh, it was this. I was trying url:"sitename". I almost forgot it. Thanks :)

Comment: Problem. It displays irrelevant websites with the site typed.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to suggest the same thing :) If this is a website you own, you can also add it to the Google Webmaster tools. It will show you lots of things about your site including number of links, pages, search terms, etc Its very useful and is free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try A1 Website Analyzer. But for all link checker software, you will have to make sure you configure them correctly to obey/not-obey (whatever your needs are) e.g robots.txt, noindex and nofollow instructions. (Common source for confusion in my experience.)